# Can one connect to a database via R and export query results as data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, odbc, rodbc

I have a R program which queries an ODBC database via the RODBC package and export the results in data.frame format via RODBC::sqlQuery. Then it converts the results in data.table format since I'm used to work with that package.

The main problem is that some of the queries return big data and sqlQuery is starting to become a bit slow. I am curious if exporting the data to R directly in data.table format would improve the performance, since I know it is faster than the usual data.frame when working with big data. But I did not find a way to do it.

Is there a way to connect to a database via R and export query results as data.table instead of data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

Big data usually means that your storage of one server is not sufficient. Databases are designed to process querys and downloading big data chunks is slow. Therefore, you should execute the SQL inside the database and not download everything to R. Take a look at `dbplyr` which allows you to compose a query in R which will then executed in the database after calling `collect()` or `compute()`

Comment: How is that different than using RODBC::sqlQuery?

Comment: `RODBC::sqlQuery` downloads the results whereas `dbplyr::compute` stores the results in a remote table circumventing slow download.

Comment: I wonder if `dbplyr::sql_save_query` could help?

Comment: @Hope There is no such function named `dbplyr::sql_save_query` in the current `dbplyr` 2.2.1. The question is more about how to make data processing faster than how to download tables into a R session.

Comment: Sorry for the negligence, the function should be `sql_query_save`, see <https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/db-sql.html>.

Comment: I do not know where `sql_query_save` is storing the temporay table. If it will be in the database, it will be fast, but if it will be an R object downloaded, it will be probably slow.